# how to check and match values that are in a range in php

Tags: php

Please I want to check if the incoming values is in the ranges below

```
80-120  and 60-80.
```

Here is my incoming values. how do I check it using if statement.

```
$a= 87
$b= 69
```

I have tried

```
    if(between($a, 80, 120 && $b, 60, 80)){
    echo 'good';
    exit();
    }


or

if($a = 80-120 && $b= 60 - 80){
    echo 'good';
    exit();
    }
```

The code above is not working. Am new to php. Thanks

Comment: `$a` must be between `80-120` and `$b` must be between `60-80`?

Comment: use `range` and `in_array` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
$a= 87;
$b= 69;
if (in_array($a, range(80, 120)) && in_array($b, range(60, 80))) {
    echo 'good';
    exit();
}
```

Here `range` method returns an array with the range of numbers between 80 & 120 and `in_array` checks whether your number is in that array.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this:

```
$range1 = range(80, 120);
$range2 = range(60, 80);
$a = 87;
$b = 69;

if(in_array($a, $range1)) {
    echo $a.' exist in range1';
} else if(in_array($b, $range1)) {
    echo $b.' exist in range1';
}if(in_array($a, $range2)) {
    echo $a.' exist in range2';
}if(in_array($b, $range2)) {
    echo $b.' exist in range2';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php):

```
filter_var($aNumber, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, 
    array(
        'options' => array(
            'min_range' => $minNumber, 
            'max_range' => $maxNumber
         )
    )
);
```

To implement that in your code:

```
if ((filter_var($a, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, 
    array(
        'options' => array(
            'min_range' => 80, 
            'max_range' => 120
         )
    )
)) && (filter_var($b, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, 
    array(
        'options' => array(
            'min_range' => 60, 
            'max_range' => 80
         )
    )
))) {
    echo '$a is between 80-120 and $b is between 60-80';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple way to achieve this is

```
if (($a> 80 && $a< 120) || ($b> 60 && $b< 80))
{
//code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**PHP code demo**](https://eval.in/775520)

`call_user_func_array("range",explode("-",$range1))` 
this will return a range of array from `80` to `120`

```
<?php
$range1='80-120';
$range2='60-80';
$a= 87;
$b= 69;
if(in_array($a, call_user_func_array("range",explode("-",$range1))))
{
    echo "In range";
}
if(in_array($b, call_user_func_array("range",explode("-",$range2))))
{
    echo "In range";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try simple with && operator like below:

```
<?php
// range 80-120  and 60-80.
$a = 87;
$b = 69;

if(($a >= 80 && $a<=120)  && ($b >= 60 && $b <= 80)){
    echo "yes a and b in the range";
}
else{
    echo "sorry a and b not in the range";
}
```